# Problem with syntax when try add trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need help with my SYNTAX error
I try to add trigger  into mysql by still have syntax error.
I will be glad for any help
When I try add this trigger i still have error 1064
Full error response is: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 19 MySQL version is 5.7

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_przejazdy_logger AFTER DELETE ON przejazdy FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO zmiany (rodzaj, data_modyfikaji, uzytkownik,
    id_pasazera, imie_nazwisko, tel_1, tel_2, tel_3, email,
    id_odbiorcy, imie_nazwisko2, tel2_1, tel2_2, dokument2,
    id_adres_z, kraj_z, miejscowosc_z, adres_z, kod_z, tel_stac_z,
    id_adres_do, kraj_do, miejscowosc_do, adres_do, kod_do, tel_stac_do, 
    data, osob, fotelik, detale, ilosc_bagazu)
(SELECT 1, CURRENT_DATE, SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', 1),
    pasazerowie.id AS id_pasazera, pasazerowie.imie_nazwisko, pasazerowie.tel_1, pasazerowie.tel_2, pasazerowie.tel_3, pasazerowie.email,
    odbiorcy.id AS id_odbiorcy, odbiorcy.imie_nazwisko AS imie_nazwisko2, odbiorcy.tel_1 AS tel2_1, odbiorcy.tel_2 AS tel2_2, odbiorcy.dokument AS dokument2,
    adresy_z.id AS id_adres_z, adresy_z.kraj AS kraj_z, adresy_z.miejscowosc AS miejscowosc_z, adresy_z.adres AS adres_z, adresy_z.kod AS kod_z, adresy_z.tel_stac AS tel_stac_z,
    adresy_do.id AS id_adres_do, adresy_do.kraj AS kraj_do, adresy_do.miejscowosc AS miejscowosc_do, adresy_do.adres AS adres_do, adresy_do.kod AS kod_do, adresy_do.tel_stac AS tel_stac_do,
    OLD.data, OLD.osob, OLD.fotelik, OLD.detale, OLD.ilosc_bagazu
FROM pasazerowie
LEFT JOIN pasazerowie odbiorcy ON OLD.id_odbiorcy = odbiorcy.id
JOIN adresy adresy_do ON OLD.id_adres_do = adresy_do.id
JOIN adresy adresy_z ON OLD.id_adres_z = adresy_z.id
WHERE pasazerowie.id = OLD.id_pasazera);
END;
```

I add triggers on this same db for logs on creating records and works fine.
Here is the code which works good:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_przejazdy_logger AFTER INSERT ON przejazdy FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO zmiany (rodzaj, data_modyfikaji, uzytkownik,
       id_pasazera, imie_nazwisko, tel_1, tel_2, tel_3, email, 
       id_odbiorcy, imie_nazwisko2, tel2_1, tel2_2, dokument2,
       id_adres_z, kraj_z, miejscowosc_z, adres_z, kod_z, tel_stac_z,
       id_adres_do, kraj_do, miejscowosc_do, adres_do, kod_do, tel_stac_do, 
       data, osob, fotelik, detale, ilosc_bagazu)
(SELECT 2, CURRENT_DATE, SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', 1),
    pasazerowie.id AS id_pasazera, pasazerowie.imie_nazwisko, pasazerowie.tel_1, pasazerowie.tel_2, pasazerowie.tel_3, pasazerowie.email,
    odbiorcy.id AS id_odbiorcy, odbiorcy.imie_nazwisko AS imie_nazwisko2, odbiorcy.tel_1 AS tel2_1, odbiorcy.tel_2 AS tel2_2, odbiorcy.dokument AS dokument2,
    adresy_z.id AS id_adres_z, adresy_z.kraj AS kraj_z, adresy_z.miejscowosc AS miejscowosc_z, adresy_z.adres AS adres_z, adresy_z.kod AS kod_z, adresy_z.tel_stac AS tel_stac_z,
    adresy_do.id AS id_adres_do, adresy_do.kraj AS kraj_do, adresy_do.miejscowosc AS miejscowosc_do, adresy_do.adres AS adres_do, adresy_do.kod AS kod_do, adresy_do.tel_stac AS tel_stac_do,
    NEW.data, NEW.osob, NEW.fotelik, NEW.detale, NEW.ilosc_bagazu
FROM pasazerowie
LEFT JOIN pasazerowie odbiorcy ON NEW.id_odbiorcy = odbiorcy.id
JOIN adresy adresy_do ON NEW.id_adres_do = adresy_do.id
JOIN adresy adresy_z ON NEW.id_adres_z = adresy_z.id
WHERE pasazerowie.id = NEW.id_pasazera);
END;
```

Comment: Please post full error

Comment: I guess you forgot to set `DELIMITER`. Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html ?

Comment: Full error respons is:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 19

MySQL version is 5.7